# Change font awesome icon color with nuxt

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome, nuxt.js

How do you change the color of a fontawesome icon in nuxt? I gave the icon a class name and set the color: #444444" but it doesn't seem to work. The font-size property worked for the icon though.

```
    <div class="icons">
      <font-awesome-icon
        :icon="['fab', 'github-square']"
        class="icons__btn icons__github"
      />
      <font-awesome-icon
        :icon="['fab', 'twitter-square']"
        class="icons__btn icons__twitter"
      />
    </div>

    .icons {
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
  &__btn {
    margin-top: 2rem;
    font-size: 5rem;
    color: red;
  }
  &__twitter {
    margin-left: 1rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you post code?

Comment: edited question with code sample

Comment: I've tested fontawesome in nuxt.js project, see answer below please.

Answer (score 1):

You should check again whether your fontawesome module is loaded right, or check again whether your css code is compiled right.

I did a demo of [use fontawesome in nuxt](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-colden-noy1s), hope it will help you.